# What is the semantics of handout overlay specification for frame environment?

Tags: beamer, handout

In the example below (when changed to `beamer` mode) there is a frame with two slides.  On the first slide the text "Text 1" is shown in red color.  On the second slide it is shown in blue color (default).

```
\documentclass[10pt,t,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<handout:2>
   {\color<1>{red}Text 1}
   {\color<2>{green}Text 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For the creation of handouts, however, I have added an overlay specification to the `frame` environment to only include slide 2 in the handouts.  I would assume that the generated slide in the handout would have "Text 1" in blue and "Text 2" in green.

Surprisingly for me the result in the handout is a slide where "Text 1" is red and "Text 2" is green.  This brought me to my question: What is the meaning of an overlay specification for `handout` mode that is added to a `frame` environment?

Please note: I already found a workaround, namely to provide individual overlay specifications for `handout` mode to the `\color` command for "Text 1":

```
{\color<1| handout:0>{red}Text 1}
```

That is, I am not asking to figure out how to make it work - I rather want to understand the background.

Update: Although I had searched SE before, only after submitting I was pointed towards this question: [Can I declare a different overlay specification in different beamer modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13087/can-i-declare-a-different-overlay-specification-in-different-beamer-modes?rq=1).  The background is, that the line

```
{\color<1>{red}Text 1}
```

actually means

```
{\color<1| handout:1->{red}Text 1}
```

Thus, if I change the line to

```
{\color<all:1>{red}Text 1}
```

then the handout is generated as I had expected.

Comment: The default is that everything gets collapsed in handout mode. So everything which happens on any slide happens on the single handout slide. Unless you say otherwise, of course. (At least, roughly speaking. It isn't always quite like this, but it is nearly like this and this is usually an effective way to think about it, I find.)